# Add percentage discount for individual product in magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, magento-rules

I need to give percentage discount for my simple products in magento and I need to show the discount amount in the front end also.

I had googled to find a solution but I could not find any. I tried to use shipping cart rules, but I need to give discount for some product only, not the whole cart amount.

I know I can assign it in special price, but there percentage value is not accepting.

Any one know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this using `Catalog Price Rules`. You can access this in backend from Top Navigation `Promotions` >> `Catalog Price Rules`.

You can specify products valid for this rule using their attribute value. Here is the screenshot for this:

[image]

Comment: Can I specify which all product I need to give percentage discount using product catalog price rule?